# how to calculate at time series in pig

Tags: apache-pig

Lets if I write `DUMP monthly`, I get:

```
(Jan,2)
(Feb,102)
(Mar,250)
(Apr,450)
(May,590)
(Jun,790)
(Jul,1040)
(Aug,1260)
(Sep,1440)
(Oct,1770)
(Nov,2000)
(Dec,2500)
```

Checking schema:

```
DESCRIBE monthly;
```

Output:

```
monthly: {group: chararray,total_case: long}
```

I need to calculate increase rate for each month. So, for February, it will be:

```
(total_case in Feb - total_case in Jan) / total_case in Jan = (102 - 2) / 2 = 50
```

For March it will be: `(250 - 102) / 102 = 1.45098039`

So, if I put the records in `monthlyIncrease`, by writing `DUMP monthlyIncrease`, I will get:

```
(Jan,0)
(Feb,50)
(Mar,1.45098039)
........
........
(Dec, 0.25)
```

Is it possible in pig? I can't think of any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible. Create a similar relation say b.Sort both relations by month. Rank both relations a,b. Join on a.rank = b.rank + 1 and then do the calculations.You will have to union the (Jan,0) record.

Assuming monthly is sorted by the group(month)

```
monthly = LOAD '/test.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (a1:chararray,a2:int);
a = rank monthly;  
b = rank monthly;   
c = join a by $0, b by ($0 + 1);  
d = foreach c generate a::a1,(double)((a::a2 - b::a2)*1.0/(b::a2)*1.0);  
e = limit monthly 1; 
f = foreach e generate e.$0,0.0; 
g = UNION d,f;
dump g;
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: I am getting error. After checking the log file, I can see this error: ERROR 2017: Internal error creating job configuration.

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias g

Comment: Made a small change, the $0 was missing in e generate e.$0

Comment: Basically, I am getting the same error from this line `dump c`. One thing I like to mention, instead of Jan, Feb, there is month number in my records in string (chararray) format for example, '01' for Jan, '02' for Feb. I hope, there is no relation with that for the error.

Comment: @user1896653 I've updated the script and attached the result.If it helps upvote/mark as answer